# Mutating a Node of a general tree in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Consider the following standard class:

```
class Node(val data: NodeData, val children: Seq[Node])
```

The `NodeData` class is also simple:

```
case class NodeData(text: String, foo: List[Bar])
```

Also, the tree has arbitrary depth, it's not fixed.

Clearly, implementing a breath-first or depth-first search on that structure is trivial with idiomatic Scala. However, consider that I want not only to visit each of these nodes, but I also want to mutate them on each visit. More concretely, I want to mutate an object in that `foo` list. How would I go about implementing this? One way I thought about this is to somehow update the nodes and build a new tree while traversing it, but my intuition tells me there is a simpler solution than that.

Comment: If it is trivial to visit each node, why isn't it trivial to just call `node.data.foo.foreach(mutate)` on each node as part of the visit?

Comment: @Tim Because in functional programming, objects should be immutable.

Comment: @MarkusAppel The OP explicitly says that they want to "mutate an object" so it is not clear whether they are looking for a functional solution or not (hence my question)

Comment: @Tim true, but the tag tells otherwise. This question would not make much sense otherwise. He is using case classes, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to stay immutable, I would define a function `recMap` on `Node`, like this:

```
def recMap(f: NodeData => NodeData) : Node = Node(f(data), children.map(_.recMap(f)))
```

You could then use it like in this example (I made `Node` a case class too):

```
type Bar = Int

case class NodeData(text: String, foo: List[Bar])

case class Node(data: NodeData, children: Seq[Node]) {

  def recMap(f: NodeData => NodeData) : Node = Node(f(data), children.map(_.recMap(f)))
}

val tree = new Node(NodeData("parent", List(1, 2, 3, 4)), Seq(
  Node(NodeData("a child", List(5, 6, 7, 8)), Seq.empty),
  Node(NodeData("another child", List(9, 10, 11, 12)), Seq.empty)
))

val modifiedTree = tree.recMap(
  data => NodeData(
    if(data.text == "parent") "I am the parent!" else "I am a child!",
    data.foo.filter(_ % 2 == 0)
  )
)

println(modifiedTree)
```

[Try it out!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MarkusA380/UOUmKODNSvSxRMvL2ouKdg/4)

Maybe that's what you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the type of solution I was looking for. I actually implemented something like that the first time, but it very error-prone, unreadable and non-idiomatic. Have a good day!

Comment: @arnaudoff Happy to hear that! Happy coding!